# RewriteRule for sitemaps in Zend Framework

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap_(.*)\.xml$ /xml/sitemap/$1 #[L]

RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Unfortunately I can not use internal Zend Framework routing for processing sitemaps, but the rules above do not work.

Sitemap URLs look like:

```
/sitemap_index.xml
/sitemap_pages.xml
/sitemap_news.xml
```

Required rewrite works fine in cases I set it R=301 redirect or comment out the last rule. Both of these are not options. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Is that `#[L]` a typo? And what exactly do your sitemap URLs look like?

Comment: You kind of need that [L] there, or else the last rule gets applied

Comment: It does not work with [L] either

Comment: Do you mind me asking? Are you going to generate a sitemap every time it is requested? I should think of a cache.

Comment: Where are the sitemap files located on the file system?

Comment: Yes, I am going to generate sitemaps when requested, but use internal Zend caching for them.

Answer (score 2):

Can't say about .htaccess. May be easier to do by zend router. Put this in the bootstrap:

```
public function _initRouter() {
    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $frontController->getRouter();
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
                    'sitemap_(.*)\.xml',
                    array(
                        'controller' => 'xml',
                        'action' => 'sitemap'
                    ),
                    array(
                        1 => 'sitemap'
                    )
    );
    $router->addRoute('sitemap', $route);
}
```

Comment: Why use PHP to serve what is (presumably) a static file sitting in the public folder?

Comment: Presumably it is not a static file, instead an action that dynamically generates sitemap so that static files don't need to be maintained. There are several reasons to do it...

Comment: Ah yes, fair point. I had assumed that the files would be static but you might be right.